# Move parent AND children in SQL Hierarchy data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, hierarchical-data

We have a table in our DB that uses the hierarchyid datatype and I am trying to find a way to reassign a parent **and** all it's children to a new parent.  I've found ways to move just the children but the parent isn't getting reassigned.  My table looks like so:

```
LocationOrg
[OrgNode] [hierarchyid] NOT NULL,
[OrgLevel]  AS ([OrgNode].[GetLevel]()),
[LocationID] [int] NOT NULL,
[LocationName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL
```

And some data:

```
LocationID  | LocationName
__________  |_____________
1           | Headquaters
2           | Location1
3           | Location2
4           | Location3
5           | Location4
6           | Location5
7           | Location6
8           | Location7
```

Right now it's setup (manually) so that Location1 & Location4 are children of Headquarters and Location2 & Location3 are children of Location1, while Location5, Location6, & Location7 are children of Location2:

```
--Headquaters
  --Location1
    --Location2
    --Location3
  --Location4
    --Location5
    --Location6
    --Location7
```

How can I write something that would reassign a parent and it's children?  For instance, if I wanted to move Location4 and all it's children under Location3:

```
--Headquaters
  --Location1
    --Location2
    --Location3
      --Location4
      --Location5
      --Location6
      --Location7
```

Please note how all the children from Location4 have become children of Location3...I don't want to move the parent/children structure as a whole, I need to reassign them to new parents.

Here's what I've got so far, but again, it only moves the children and not it's parent:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[ReorderLocationOrg]
    @LocationID int,
    @NewParentLocationID int
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @OldParent hierarchyid, 
        @NewParent hierarchyid

    SELECT @OldParent = OrgNode 
    FROM LocationOrg
    WHERE LocationID = @LocationID;

    SELECT @NewParent = OrgNode 
    FROM LocationOrg
    WHERE LocationID = @NewParentLocationID;

    DECLARE children_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT OrgNode 
        FROM LocationOrg
        WHERE OrgNode.GetAncestor(1) = @OldParent;

        DECLARE @ChildId hierarchyid;
        OPEN children_cursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM children_cursor INTO @ChildId;
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
        START:
            DECLARE @NewId hierarchyid;
            SELECT @NewId = @NewParent.GetDescendant(MAX(OrgNode), NULL)
            FROM LocationOrg 
            WHERE OrgNode.GetAncestor(1) = @NewParent;

            UPDATE LocationOrg
            SET OrgNode = OrgNode.GetReparentedValue(@ChildId, @NewId)
            WHERE OrgNode.IsDescendantOf(@ChildId) = 1;
            IF @@error <> 0 GOTO START -- On error, retry
                FETCH NEXT FROM children_cursor INTO @ChildId;

        END
    CLOSE children_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE children_cursor;

    --Move Parent to new node.
    --UPDATE LocationOrg
    --SET OrgNode = @OldParent.GetReparentedValue(@OldParent2, @NewParent)
    --WHERE OrgNode = @OldParent
END
```

As you can see (commented out section), I tried to move the parent, after the cursor, but it throws an error stating a duplicate record cannot be inserted.

I've looked at this link on [Moving Subtrees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx#BKMK_MovingSubtrees) but that procedure moves the parent and child while keeping their structure, so in my case, Location4 would be moved under Location3 but Locations 5, 6, & 7 would still be a child of Location4, not 3...which is what I don't want.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The duplicate error is most probably caused by the fact that you are moving the oldParent node to a position already occupied under the new parent node.

Try this to move the old parent node in your sp (after the cursor)

```
--Get a new Hierarchical id for you record
DECLARE @NewOldParentId hierarchyid
SELECT @NewOldParentId = @NewParent.GetDescendant(MAX(OrgNode), NULL)
FROM LocationOrg 
WHERE OrgNode.GetAncestor(1) = @NewParent;

--Give this new id to the oldParent
UPDATE LocationOrg
SET OrgNode = @NewOldParentId
WHERE LocationID = @LocationID;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late response, but my solution to a similar problem was to move based on the grandparent rather than the direct parent.

In my example I have a 4 Categories that populate 4 dropdown lists. I am using a hierarchy table to keep track of the dependencies.

In my update where clause I get the descendants of the grandparent and move the id's that also only descendants of the child (the element I care about)
I include the last <> @parentId as an additional check (which is needed in the application).

```
    DECLARE @childID hierarchyid = (select id from DataCategories where Category_ID = 1) --the node I care about
    DECLARE @oldParentID hierarchyid = @childID.GetAncestor(1) --direct parent
    DECLARE @oldGrandParentID hierarchyid = @childID.GetAncestor(2) --grandparent
    DECLARE @newParentID hierarchyid = (select id from DataCategories where Category_ID = 2) -- target parent

    UPDATE DataCategories
        SET id = id.GetReparentedValue(@oldParentID, @newParentID)
        WHERE id.IsDescendantOf(@oldGrandParentID) = 1 AND id.IsDescendantOf(@childID) = 1 AND id <> @oldParentID
```